I have implemented a ShuffleJS select dropdown but there are a few glitches
I want to use ShuffleJS (see https://vestride.github.io/Shuffle) to filter out items on a <select> list by typing my search keyword on the <select>'s input text area and the items in the <select> dropdown to be filtered out dynamically as I type. Unfortunately I have not managed this. And so, I followed the idea in How to add shufflejs for select tag which suggests creating a DIY <select> of some sorts which then ShuffleJS seems to handle OK.
So, instead of using a <select>:

I create a <textarea> to type my search. It will act the same as the textarea of a <select>,
I stored all items (to be filtered out) as <li> elements inside a <ul>,
I let ShuffleJS know where these are located.

I have one complication which I think I handled well:
My option items form a very long list and I have two or more of those search-and-select elements in my form with the exact same option items. For example they can be From/To locations in a map, train stops, etc. And so I decided to use only 1 list of option items (the train stops) to be shared among many From/To/etc. search text areas in the same page/form.
This works mostly OK but there are a few problems that I need help with:

The most important problem is with the logic of closing the "dropdown" containing the items to be filtered/selected when the user has made a selection by clicking on an option item in the "dropdown" or user has not made a selection by clicking elsewhere in the form. (By "dropdown" I mean the thing that pops up when I click on the search text area and contains, initially, all the option items, later to be filtered out as I type in that area.). I detect that the user has clicked on somewhere outside the search text area by the onblur event. In which case I close the "dropdown" and clear the search area with no selection by the user. This works fine. However, when the user clicks on an item on the "dropdown" with the intention to select an option item, this is still considered an onblur event for the search textarea and it is handled first, i.e. no selection, text area is cleared. By the time this is handled, there is no "dropdown" and the onclick on the option item fails. I solved this by delaying the onblur for a few milliseconds hoping that the onclick will be handled first, save the user selection and then close the "dropdown". This works but I suspect there is a race condition looming there and I am not comfortable with this. Is there any better solution?

I would like to make the options dropdown appear not only when I click on the search textarea but also when I use the keyboard to navigate the elements, using the TAB key. the onfocus event does not seem to work.

When I click on a search text area and the "dropdown" appears with all the options, I can not just click on one and select it if I don't first type something in the text area in order for ShuffleJS to do some filtering, even if I erase my typing afterwards (so as to obtain the unfiltered list of option items). In this situation (i.e. without first typing a search term), clicking on an option does not copy it onto the text area and closing the "dropdown". Why is that and do you have any hints on how I can fix it?


I don't use any framework. Just javascript and ShuffleJS (perhaps bootstrap/jquery).
Edit: I have a fiddle for this here : https://jsfiddle.net/bliako/8sm13gx9/11/
The code is below:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
  <title>ShuffleJS select dropdown example</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/w3-css/4.1.0/w3.css" />

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Shuffle/6.1.0/shuffle.min.js" integrity="sha512-r8mIpk3ypCMwNxH6srRZGbjHQlOFt3Mq2vrZ/iymx6g9JUqTeVavofeX6gbrxAC74X5HmBy5gxyhCm6OiXrM0Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <form id="searchform" name="searchform" class="myappsearch" action=''>
      <div class="form-group col">
        <!-- begin the A search text area -->
        <legend><span>Select A <small>(onblur is handled with a timeout after onclick, works)</small>:</span></legend>
        <textarea class="form-control form-control-sm  filter__search js-shuffle-search" id="search-textarea-A" type="search" rows="1" required onkeydown='handle_keydown_in_search_textarea(this, event);' onblur='this.value = ""; mythis = this; setTimeout(function() { close_shuffle_dropdown(mythis); }, 200);'
          onclick='A_clicked(this);'></textarea>
        <!-- this is a lame solution to the dropdown disappearing before the
     onclick event on it is handled: Just act on the onblur after some
     milliseconds so that the onclick has time to be handled first:
                  onblur='close_shuffle_dropdown(this);'

      onblur='this.value = ""; mythis = this; setTimeout(function() { close_shuffle_dropdown(mythis); }, 200);'
-->
      </div>
      <!-- end the A search text area: -->
      <br />

      <div class="form-group col">
        <!-- begin the Select B search text area -->
        <legend><span>Select B <small>(onblur is handled before onclick, problem)</small>:</span></legend>
        <textarea class="form-control form-control-sm  filter__search js-shuffle-search" id="search-textarea-B" type="search" rows="1" required onkeydown='handle_keydown_in_search_textarea(this, event);' onblur='close_shuffle_dropdown(this);' onclick='B_clicked(this);'></textarea>
      </div>
      <!-- end the Select B search text area -->
    </form>
  </div>

  <!-- this UL contains all the available options to select
     Shufflejs displays this in its own way in a "dropdown"
     and then, by typing on ANY of the two search textareas
     you can see the options filtered out.
     Clicking on an option will copy the value of
     that option to the respective search textarea (we have two!)
-->
  <div id='select-options-container' class='custom-select' style='display:none; position:absolute;'>
    <ul id='select-options' style='background:#000000;width:100px;'>
      <li class='select-item' style='color:#ffffff;' id='Orange' onclick='item_has_been_selected(this);'>Orange</li>
      <li class='select-item' style='color:#ffffff;' id='Black' onclick='item_has_been_selected(this);'>Black</li>
      <li class='select-item' style='color:#ffffff;' id='Green123' onclick='item_has_been_selected(this);'>Green123</li>
      <li class='select-item' style='color:#ffffff;' id='Green567' onclick='item_has_been_selected(this);'>Green567</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <script>
    var Shuffle = window.Shuffle;
    var currentSearchTextarea = null;

    class ShufflejsFilterer {
      constructor(element) {
        this.element = element;
        this.shuffle = new Shuffle(element, {
          itemSelector: '.select-item',
          //sizer: element.querySelector('.my-sizer-element'),
        });

        this._activeFilters = [];

        // Log events:
        //this.addShuffleEventListeners();

        // create the search filter:
        this.addSearchFilter();
      }

      /**
       * Shuffle uses the CustomEvent constructor to dispatch events. You can listen
       * for them like you normally would (with jQuery for example).
       */
      addShuffleEventListeners() {
        this.shuffle.on(Shuffle.EventType.LAYOUT, (data) => {
          console.log('layout. data:', data);
        });
        this.shuffle.on(Shuffle.EventType.REMOVED, (data) => {
          console.log('removed. data:', data);
        });
      }

      // Advanced filtering
      addSearchFilter() {
        // modified to handle more than 1 search-boxes
        const searchInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.js-shuffle-search');
        if (searchInputs.length == 0) {
          return;
        }
        // no we call this on our
        //    searchInputs.forEach( (asearchInput) => {
        //      asearchInput.addEventListener('keydown', this._handleSearchKeydown.bind(this));
        //    });
      }

      /**
       * Filter the shuffle instance by items with a title that matches the search input.
       * @param {Event} evt Event object.
       */
      _handleSearchKeydown(evt) {
        // this is e.g. the Search textarea A or B
        currentSearchTextarea = evt.target;
        // and this is what the user has typed as a search text
        const searchText = evt.target.value.toLowerCase();
        console.log("searching with this " + searchText);
        this.shuffle.filter((element, shuffle) => {
          // get the text content of the client element which is
          // the text (or anything else via data-attributes)
          // of each element part of the select-items set
          const contents = element.textContent.toLowerCase().trim();
          // and filter it out if it does not contain our search text
          return contents.indexOf(searchText) !== -1;
        });
      }
    } // end class ShufflejsFilterer

    ///////////////////////////////////////
    /// other JS functions
    ///////////////////////////////////////

    function handle_keydown_in_search_textarea(
      caller_obj,
      event
    ) {
      if (event.keyCode == 27) {
        // on ESCape close the shuffle-dropdown and select nothing
        caller_obj.value = '';
        close_shuffle_dropdown(caller_obj);
        return; // nothing to do
      }
      // let ShuffleJS handle it now
      window.myFilterer._handleSearchKeydown(event);
    }

    function close_shuffle_dropdown(
      caller_obj
    ) {
      console.log("close_shuffle_dropdown() : called ...");
      var selObj = document.getElementById('select-options-container');
      //selObj.style.position = 'absolute'; // already set
      selObj.style.display = 'none'; // hide
      // we need to reset the contents of the <ul>
      // if you don't complete (by clicking an item of the <ul>)
      // the <ul> appears truncated but search text is empty.
      // this is what causes it to reset!!!! it is part of _init()
      window.myFilterer.shuffle.filter(window.myFilterer.shuffle.options.group, window.myFilterer.shuffle.options.initialSort);
    }

    function item_has_been_selected(
      item_obj
    ) {
      // once an item has been selected we copy its value to the currently
      // selected textarea:
      currentSearchTextarea.value = item_obj.textContent;
      // and then we close the shuffle dropdown:
      document.getElementById("select-options-container").style.display = "none";
    }

    // Search textarea (A) was clicked, so we show the shuffle dropdown
    function A_clicked(
      obj
    ) {
      const pos = obj.getBoundingClientRect();
      var selObj = document.getElementById('select-options-container');
      /* place the "dropdown" with all the select items in there,
         as formatted by Shufflejs, under the client element
             (search textarea)
      */
      //selObj.style.position = 'absolute'; // already set
      selObj.style.left = pos.left + 'px';
      selObj.style.top = String(pos.bottom + 10) + 'px';
      // and show the "dropdown"
      selObj.style.display = 'inline';
    }
    // Search textarea (B) was clicked, so we show the shuffle dropdown
    // it is the same as the above
    function B_clicked(
      obj
    ) {
      console.log("my val: " + obj.value);
      A_clicked(obj);
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////
    /// things to do when DOM loaded:
    ///////////////////////////////////////

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      // create the Shufflejs filterer
      window.myFilterer = new ShufflejsFilterer(document.getElementById('select-options'));

      /*
      window.myFilterer.applyCss({
          INITIAL: {
            position: 'absolute',
            top: 0,
            visibility: 'visible',
            willChange: 'transform',
          }
      });
      */


      ['search-textarea-A', 'search-textarea-B'].forEach((k) => {
        var obj = document.getElementById(k);
        obj.value = '';
      });
    }); // end DOMContentLoaded
  </script>
</body>

</html>




the question as a whole might be very broad to address... but before saying anything else did you consider something like https://select2.org/dropdown instead of using shuffleJS? I ask because it seems to me you just need a dropdown with filtering option and you are using a more advanced tool intended for a different task that requires you to implement many behaviours on your own. For example what you called a lame solution is actually known as debouncing and pretty legit. Anyway before spending efforts on your current approach I want to be sure you considered select2 first

thank you @DiegoD for looking at my question. Your suggestion looks promising. I will let people know in this thread. Thank you.

select2 works fine for my use-case. I have managed to add data-attributes to my items. What I miss now is to be able to use my huge dataset to populate a single "dropdown" for two or more form items. I do not want it duplicated in many  all holding the same data. For example: suppose my dataset is all the names of people in office. And I have 5  populated with the same list of people (so the list is 5-plicated!) just to fill a form of which 5 are part of the first aid team. Ideally the dropdown must be "mobile". This is what I have done above. Any pointers for select2?

select2 can both use the <option> already populating the <select> you are binding or just use an external data source when you initialize it. Here there's a full guide on that https://select2.org/data-sources .. and here in particular https://select2.org/data-sources/arrays .. by the way if you ask another question focusing on what you have done so far with select2 and what you are missing, you'll easily receive a better feedback. You may also find already existing answer on that matter here on SO

when you say floating it's not very meaningful.. as long as you have 5 distinct selects .. each one of them requires to have its own dataset despite being duplicated. But the point is you don't need to have it already hardcoded in the html. Such data can be an array defined once (or retrieved from an ajax request in real time) and be used to populate 5 different selects with 5 single statements

thank you very much @DiegoD ++ I will move to select2 for this particular use-case.
